# JOOQ MySQL DATETIME Type

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm trying to generate this simple SQL with JOOQ and for some reason I can't get it done. I want the following code to be generated for MySQL databases.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    F DATETIME
);
```

I expected it to be something like

```
dsl.createTable(name("T"))
   .column("F", MySQLDataType.DATETIME);
```

Unfortunately, `MySQLDataType` is deprecated. JOOQ explicitly says to only use types declared in `SQLDataType`, but for some reason I can't find any.

I've already tried with `DATE`, `LOCALDATE`, `LOCALDATETIME` but all of them generate a `TIMESTAMP` field.

---

I'm using JOOQ to generate DDL for MySQL and Oracle DBMS' at the same time. Oracle types are generated fine (I get `DATE` and it's all right) but MySQL only gives me `TIMESTAMP`s.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialect specific data types were deprecated with [#7375](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7375) in jOOQ 3.11, unfortunately without replacement functionality yet. The replacement will be implemented no earlier than jOOQ 3.13 (maybe later) through [#5713](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5713), a much more powerful, dynamic data type registry - as opposed to the current static one, which depends completely on internal API and static initialisation.

For the time being, you can continue using `MySQLDataType.DATETIME` in your case, or create your own `DefaultDataType` instance for it. The two approaches are equally unsafe, one being deprecated, the other relying on internal API.

The deprecated types will not be removed for quite a while, though, for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: As you're the leading developer of the project I assume you speak the truth. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the corresponding SQLDataType instead.
link:[official api](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/mysql/MySQLDataType.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. All of the types in that page are deprecated 'cause they're DBMS specific and, in fact, I'm using JOOQ to generate code for MySQL and Oracle at the same time. Oracle types are generated fine but MySQL only gives me TIMESTAMPs, where I need DATETIME instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
In jooq 3.13.2
<generator>
     <generate>
     <javaTimeTypes>false</javaTimeTypes>
     </generate>
...
```

To force timestamp usage

[jooq manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-java-time-types/)